# Center Path inside SVG

Tags: html, xml, svg, path

Is it possible to center a path vertically within an SVG element?

This is one of the paths I need to center:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 144 144"><path d="M127.782 40.348H15.802c-3.813 0-6.912 3.002-6.912 6.766v14.113c0 3.235 1.52 6.11 3.953 7.92h-.012s52.9 35.873 53.09 36c1.56.978 3.82 1.886 5.82 1.886 2.21 0 4.25-.71 5.9-1.886l52.54-35.675c2.69-1.78 4.494-4.81 4.494-8.246V47.194c0-3.772-3.07-6.846-6.885-6.846zm-38.05 29.864c-.066 1.966-.685 3.392-2.68 3.392H64.744c0 4.482 4.56 6.735 8.77 6.735 7.825 0 9.407-4.4 12.117-3.34 1.49.58 2.14 1.62 2.11 3.62-.08 4.48-5.292 7.864-14.94 7.864-11.637 0-19-6.573-19-17.353 0-10.31 7.63-17.88 18.184-17.88 10.465 0 17.757 7.04 17.757 16.74v.215zm-17.91-8.494c-3.434 0-6.28 2.284-6.695 5.597h13.47c-.068-3.45-3.116-5.597-6.776-5.597zm-.087 53.697c-3.328-.038-6.947-1.51-8.567-2.805L8.86 75.7v52.492c0 3.764 3.065 6.808 6.88 6.808h111.983c3.824 0 6.944-3.044 6.944-6.808v-52.49L80.53 112.61c-2.586 1.832-5.636 2.84-8.795 2.805z"/></svg>
```

Comment: [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/image) have a great tool to center paths to any direction

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you mean automatically, without intervention, then no.  However you can add a transform to the path to centre it in the SVG.

The bounding box for the path is:

```
{
   x: 8.859999656677246,
   y: 40.347999572753906,
   width: 125.81500244140625,
   height: 94.6520004272461
}
```

The height of the document is 144, so the y should actually be at:

```
(144 - 94.652) / 2 = 24.674
```

So the y position of the path has to be adjusted by:

```
(24.674 - 40.348) = -15.674
```

So add the following attribute to the path element:

```
transform="translate(0, -15.674)"
```

Demo before and after:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 144 144" style="background-color: gray"><path d="M127.782 40.348H15.802c-3.813 0-6.912 3.002-6.912 6.766v14.113c0 3.235 1.52 6.11 3.953 7.92h-.012s52.9 35.873 53.09 36c1.56.978 3.82 1.886 5.82 1.886 2.21 0 4.25-.71 5.9-1.886l52.54-35.675c2.69-1.78 4.494-4.81 4.494-8.246V47.194c0-3.772-3.07-6.846-6.885-6.846zm-38.05 29.864c-.066 1.966-.685 3.392-2.68 3.392H64.744c0 4.482 4.56 6.735 8.77 6.735 7.825 0 9.407-4.4 12.117-3.34 1.49.58 2.14 1.62 2.11 3.62-.08 4.48-5.292 7.864-14.94 7.864-11.637 0-19-6.573-19-17.353 0-10.31 7.63-17.88 18.184-17.88 10.465 0 17.757 7.04 17.757 16.74v.215zm-17.91-8.494c-3.434 0-6.28 2.284-6.695 5.597h13.47c-.068-3.45-3.116-5.597-6.776-5.597zm-.087 53.697c-3.328-.038-6.947-1.51-8.567-2.805L8.86 75.7v52.492c0 3.764 3.065 6.808 6.88 6.808h111.983c3.824 0 6.944-3.044 6.944-6.808v-52.49L80.53 112.61c-2.586 1.832-5.636 2.84-8.795 2.805z"/></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 144 144" style="background-color: gray">
  
  <path transform="translate(0, -15.674)"
        d="M127.782 40.348H15.802c-3.813 0-6.912 3.002-6.912 6.766v14.113c0 3.235 1.52 6.11 3.953 7.92h-.012s52.9 35.873 53.09 36c1.56.978 3.82 1.886 5.82 1.886 2.21 0 4.25-.71 5.9-1.886l52.54-35.675c2.69-1.78 4.494-4.81 4.494-8.246V47.194c0-3.772-3.07-6.846-6.885-6.846zm-38.05 29.864c-.066 1.966-.685 3.392-2.68 3.392H64.744c0 4.482 4.56 6.735 8.77 6.735 7.825 0 9.407-4.4 12.117-3.34 1.49.58 2.14 1.62 2.11 3.62-.08 4.48-5.292 7.864-14.94 7.864-11.637 0-19-6.573-19-17.353 0-10.31 7.63-17.88 18.184-17.88 10.465 0 17.757 7.04 17.757 16.74v.215zm-17.91-8.494c-3.434 0-6.28 2.284-6.695 5.597h13.47c-.068-3.45-3.116-5.597-6.776-5.597zm-.087 53.697c-3.328-.038-6.947-1.51-8.567-2.805L8.86 75.7v52.492c0 3.764 3.065 6.808 6.88 6.808h111.983c3.824 0 6.944-3.044 6.944-6.808v-52.49L80.53 112.61c-2.586 1.832-5.636 2.84-8.795 2.805z"/></svg>
```

Comment: That works for this icon... I have 300 more with varying heights. Is there a quick way to apply this method to all of them automagically? I see SVGO offers a "vertical align" plugin, but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: From a brief examination of the source, it looks like that plugin requires that the SVG have a "height" attribute, which yours don't have.  Perhaps there is a plugin (or maybe you can write one) that adds an appropriate height (in this case 144) before applying the vertical align.  Then remove the height again.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the [svg `viewBox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) to center the path. This is especially useful if you have several paths in the svg, so you do not have to add a transform to each one.

> The value of the `viewBox` attribute is a list of four numbers: `min-x min-y width height`. The numbers specify a rectangle in user space which is mapped to the bounds of the viewport established for the associated SVG element

In your example that would be `viewBox="0 15.674 144 144"`, getting the y-offset the same way as in Pauls answer.

Demo before and after:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 144 144" width="300" height="300" style="background-color: gray">
  <path d="M127.782 40.348H15.802c-3.813 0-6.912 3.002-6.912 6.766v14.113c0 3.235 1.52 6.11 3.953 7.92h-.012s52.9 35.873 53.09 36c1.56.978 3.82 1.886 5.82 1.886 2.21 0 4.25-.71 5.9-1.886l52.54-35.675c2.69-1.78 4.494-4.81 4.494-8.246V47.194c0-3.772-3.07-6.846-6.885-6.846zm-38.05 29.864c-.066 1.966-.685 3.392-2.68 3.392H64.744c0 4.482 4.56 6.735 8.77 6.735 7.825 0 9.407-4.4 12.117-3.34 1.49.58 2.14 1.62 2.11 3.62-.08 4.48-5.292 7.864-14.94 7.864-11.637 0-19-6.573-19-17.353 0-10.31 7.63-17.88 18.184-17.88 10.465 0 17.757 7.04 17.757 16.74v.215zm-17.91-8.494c-3.434 0-6.28 2.284-6.695 5.597h13.47c-.068-3.45-3.116-5.597-6.776-5.597zm-.087 53.697c-3.328-.038-6.947-1.51-8.567-2.805L8.86 75.7v52.492c0 3.764 3.065 6.808 6.88 6.808h111.983c3.824 0 6.944-3.044 6.944-6.808v-52.49L80.53 112.61c-2.586 1.832-5.636 2.84-8.795 2.805z"/>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 15.674 144 144" width="300" height="300" style="background-color: gray">
  <path d="M127.782 40.348H15.802c-3.813 0-6.912 3.002-6.912 6.766v14.113c0 3.235 1.52 6.11 3.953 7.92h-.012s52.9 35.873 53.09 36c1.56.978 3.82 1.886 5.82 1.886 2.21 0 4.25-.71 5.9-1.886l52.54-35.675c2.69-1.78 4.494-4.81 4.494-8.246V47.194c0-3.772-3.07-6.846-6.885-6.846zm-38.05 29.864c-.066 1.966-.685 3.392-2.68 3.392H64.744c0 4.482 4.56 6.735 8.77 6.735 7.825 0 9.407-4.4 12.117-3.34 1.49.58 2.14 1.62 2.11 3.62-.08 4.48-5.292 7.864-14.94 7.864-11.637 0-19-6.573-19-17.353 0-10.31 7.63-17.88 18.184-17.88 10.465 0 17.757 7.04 17.757 16.74v.215zm-17.91-8.494c-3.434 0-6.28 2.284-6.695 5.597h13.47c-.068-3.45-3.116-5.597-6.776-5.597zm-.087 53.697c-3.328-.038-6.947-1.51-8.567-2.805L8.86 75.7v52.492c0 3.764 3.065 6.808 6.88 6.808h111.983c3.824 0 6.944-3.044 6.944-6.808v-52.49L80.53 112.61c-2.586 1.832-5.636 2.84-8.795 2.805z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How did you calculate `viewBox="0 15.674 144 144"`?